# Post content on friend's wall in facebook

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I want to post on some content on my facebook's friends but my below code is not working.
I have set the permissions of publish_action publish_stream,status_update in my developer APP.

This is the below code:-

```
require_once 'src/facebook.php'; 
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId'  => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX', 
        'secret' => 'XXXXXXXXXXX', 
  ));
$user = $facebook->getUser();
$_var = $facebook->getAccessToken();
if ($user)
{ 
    try
    {
                $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me'); 
                $friends = $facebook->api('/me/friends');

                 foreach($friends['data'] as $friend) {
        $facebook->api('/'.$friend['id'].'/feed', 'post', array(
                  'message' => 'just a test message',

          ));

 }


 }


catch(Exception $e){
             echo "errorr";
             }
}
```

Plz provide me some solutions

Comment: What's the meaning of _not working_ ? **The try lost his Catch.

Comment: In my code i have also write catch statement,but above i have not nentioned it.

Comment: Have you enabled error display, any warnings, errors or exceptions?

Comment: Do you know one of FBs share features? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/web/share - maybe you do not need your on server posting. What's your use case?

Comment: Now I have updated my code. It gives error